# Alamofire HTTPS change in 10.3

Tags: swift, https, alamofire, ios10

I'm currently using Alamofire with a project and am seeing an issue around the 10.3 beta with different functionality. I have the same project running fine in an iOS 10.2 simulator where I am making a get request to an HTTPS url using a self-signed certificate. When I run the same code against the iOS 10.3 simulator with the same certificates installed the response returned back is:

kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802

Would anyone have some suggestions on where to look?

Comment: did you add **App Transport Security** in your **plist** ?

Comment: Prior to installing the certificates I had the ATS settings included in the project Info.plist but removed those once the certificate trust was setup on the device. When testing with a different URL without a self-signed certificate the request comes back OK - so it makes me think it is more of an iOS change in regards to certificate handling than code.

Comment: The location for trusting a self-signed certificate has changed in 10.3. That is now located in Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings.

Comment: @RandySaeks do you solve this problem ?

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander - The self-signed certificates now need to be trusted on the device in a new location. In Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings there is now an On / Off toggle that should get things going.